# ¿Como rellenar la clave de un array con valores que vienen de otro array?

Tags: javascript, angular

Tengo 2 arrays que vienen desde mi API.

```
dataArray: Array(4)
0: {_id: "5f1dd4b7c3ede500f8d443cd", titulo: "motorola e4", descripcionArticulo: "smartphone", precio: 90, foto: "uploads\6ba1d33b-f48c-4e5f-9855-96228d30a252.jpg", …}
1: {_id: "5f1de7e4f3a0621c147c261e", titulo: "mouse", descripcionArticulo: "para programar", precio: 90, foto: "uploads\2630bade-c4c1-49fc-afe2-7a8713e164e2.png", …}
2: {_id: "5f1de7e4f3a0621c147c261e", titulo: "mouse", descripcionArticulo: "para programar", precio: 90, foto: "uploads\2630bade-c4c1-49fc-afe2-7a8713e164e2.png", …}
3: {_id: "5f1de7e4f3a0621c147c261e", titulo: "mouse", descripcionArticulo: "para programar", precio: 90, foto: "uploads\2630bade-c4c1-49fc-afe2-7a8713e164e2.png", …}

withId: Array(4)
0: {_id: "5f1de7c4f3a0621c147c261d", idArticle: "5f1dd4b7c3ede500f8d443cd", idUser: "5efea5c04714c71c60e1f3f2", __v: 0}
1: {_id: "5f1de7f2f3a0621c147c261f", idArticle: "5f1de7e4f3a0621c147c261e", idUser: "5efea5c04714c71c60e1f3f2", __v: 0}
2: {_id: "5f1de807f3a0621c147c2620", idArticle: "5f1de7e4f3a0621c147c261e", idUser: "5efea5c04714c71c60e1f3f2", __v: 0}
3: {_id: "5f1de810f3a0621c147c2621", idArticle: "5f1de7e4f3a0621c147c261e", idUser:
```

y quiero agregarle una clave para todos los objetos de **dataArray** que sea **idCompra** y rellenar cada **idCompra** con el valor del **_id** del array **withId**

Actualmente estoy haciendo esto

```
let newArray = res.dataArray
      newArray.forEach((data,index) => {
       
        res.withId.forEach(data2 => {
             newArray[index].newClave = data2._id
        })
```

})

Pero solo almacena en idCompra el ultimo _id del array withId cuando requiero es rellenarlos uno por uno.
Es decir que quede asi algo asi

```
0:
descripcionArticulo: "smartphone"
foto: "uploads\6ba1d33b-f48c-4e5f-9855-96228d30a252.jpg"
idSeller: "5ed01bdd5f679102e857c099"
newClave: "5f1de7c4f3a0621c147c261d"
precio: 90
titulo: "motorola e4"
uniqueId: "3c02fef9-8920-42b9-bd12-a97583067915"
__v: 0
_id: "5f1dd4b7c3ede500f8d443cd"
__proto__: Object,

1:
descripcionArticulo: "para programar"
foto: "uploads\2630bade-c4c1-49fc-afe2-7a8713e164e2.png"
idSeller: "5ed01bdd5f679102e857c099"
newClave: "5f1de7f2f3a0621c147c261f"
precio: 90
titulo: "mouse"
__v: 0
_id: "5f1de7e4f3a0621c147c261e"
__proto__: Object
```

Disculpen si la pregunta es muy larga

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si es como entiendo, seria recorrer los dos array en paralelo, asi:

```js
dataArray = [
{_id: "5f1dd4b7c3ede500f8d443cd", titulo: "motorola e4", descripcionArticulo: "smartphone", precio: 90, foto: "uploads\6ba1d33b-f48c-4e5f-9855-96228d30a252.jpg"},
{_id: "5f1de7e4f3a0621c147c261e", titulo: "mouse", descripcionArticulo: "para programar", precio: 90, foto: "uploads\2630bade-c4c1-49fc-afe2-7a8713e164e2.png"},
{_id: "5f1de7e4f3a0621c147c261e", titulo: "mouse", descripcionArticulo: "para programar", precio: 90, foto: "uploads\2630bade-c4c1-49fc-afe2-7a8713e164e2.png"},
{_id: "5f1de7e4f3a0621c147c261e", titulo: "mouse", descripcionArticulo: "para programar", precio: 90, foto: "uploads\2630bade-c4c1-49fc-afe2-7a8713e164e2.png"},
]
withId = [
{_id: "5f1de7c4f3a0621c147c261d", idArticle: "5f1dd4b7c3ede500f8d443cd", idUser: "5efea5c04714c71c60e1f3f2", __v: 0},
{_id: "5f1de7f2f3a0621c147c261f", idArticle: "5f1de7e4f3a0621c147c261e", idUser: "5efea5c04714c71c60e1f3f2", __v: 0},
{_id: "5f1de807f3a0621c147c2620", idArticle: "5f1de7e4f3a0621c147c261e", idUser: "5efea5c04714c71c60e1f3f2", __v: 0},
{_id: "5f1de810f3a0621c147c2621", idArticle: "5f1de7e4f3a0621c147c261e", idUser: "5efea5c04714c71c60e1f3f2", __v: 0}
]
dataArray.forEach((data, index) => {
    data.idCompra = withId[index]._id;
})
console.log(dataArray)
```